# Unlock Note 5 phone

Tags: lock-screens

I was using my thumb print to access my phone, restarted my phone, and then it asked for my password; my thumb print would no longer work. I was driving so I input my password about an hour later and it did not work.  It started out, try again in 5 minutes and now up to try again in an hour.  I went to Android manager to try to lock the phone to get a new password and it worked but a message came back to me saying my phone was already locked and the new password would not work.  So, I need Android manager to unlock my phone.  I have been locked out since September 2016.  I do not want my phone wiped cleaned because I have valuable files on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung devices, if you’ve logged into the device with a Samsung account, you can go to the [Samsung Find My Mobile](https://findmymobile.samsung.com/), log in with the same Samsung account, and use the “Unlock my screen” option to remotely remove your device’s lock screen. Other manufacturers might potentially offer similar features if they have a device-tracking website if you’ve signed up for.

Hope this works for you! Good luck!